# How to export data and its relationships

Tags: xml, database, export

we do have a client server application with database. Now our customer wants to have the following feature:

He wants to enter a ProductNumber and wants to know what kind of entities we have stored in our database and what relationships they have. E.g. ProductNumber "1239293" has Customer "A" and "B" also there are some product attributes associated with. 
So to say it is an export of our Database to a flat file.

My question now is: What would be a good output-format ?

- The data is hierarchical
- The output should be readable to the customer

The only solution I can think of is XML. Can you suggest others?

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server had a number of command line exe which may do the job.

Comment: we use DB2. However I am mainly interested in which output format would be best

Comment: XML is good.  You can use CSV which is easy to input.  Fixed space columns is nice because it is easy for a person to read.